# How to filter a list of tuples (or a list of lists) to remove all values that = 0?

Tags: python

I originally had a vector, which I attached an index to, as shown below.

```
keys = list(enumerate(x))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0.0), (1, 0.87), (2, 0.0), (3, 0.0), (4, 0.0), (5, 0.32), (6, 0.46), (7, 0.0), (8, 0.0), (9, 0.1), (10, 0.0), (11, 0.0)]
```

What I'm trying to do is remove all the tuples where the 2nd value is 0.0. I've also attempted to do this with a list of lists which is otherwise identical to the above data, instead of a list of tuples, but I haven't been able to get a loop or a lambda value to work in this way. So I already have

This is an intermediate step of what I'm trying to do (from there I'd unzip the list and put it into a dict with the first value as the keys and the second value as the values).

Comment: Please provide `x`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I don't think it's needed, as OP provided a sample list of tuples.

Comment: @AnisR. But my solution needs `x`.

Comment: @AnisR. And it would be good for *everyone's* testing of their own code and the code of others. How can I for example try out @iz_'s solutions if I don't have `x`?

Comment: apologies, i was trying to keep it as minimal as possible.

x = [0.0, 0.87, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.32, 0.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.10, 0.0, 0.0]

Answer (score 5):

Use a list comprehension:

```
keys = [(idx, val) for idx, val in enumerate(x) if val]
```

To make it a `dict`:

```
result_dict = {idx: val for idx, val in enumerate(x) if val}
```

Answer (score 2):

A rare case where I get to use `itertools.compress`.

```
>>> dict(compress(enumerate(x), x))
{1: 0.87, 5: 0.32, 6: 0.46, 9: 0.1}
```

Comment: nicely done, rarely get to see `compress` in the wild

Comment: @aws_apprentice It's so rare that the documentation is even wrong and apparently noone cares :-) (it says "selectors that evaluates to `True`", should say "true")